# Download Stripe invoice through Java with defined language

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I'm working on a Spring Boot application with integration of Stripe for payment management.

When a user is dealing with a payment, an invoice is generated through Stripe.
Application downloads this invoice from Stripe to copy it in a Cloud provider using S3 API.
All of this is working correctly.

My concern is application users can choose different language.

When downloading Stripe invoice through Stripe dashboard, invoice is automatically generated in language defined in web browser.
I would like to be able to "set" the language when downloading invoice through API depending on user settings.

Here is how my current code looks like:

```
public void copyInvoice(Etude etude, String invoiceName, URL invoiceURL, String bucketName) {      
        var invoiceTmp = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + invoiceName);
        try {
            var defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            log.debug("copyInvoice - defaultLocale : {}", defaultLocale);
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(invoiceDTO.getUrl(), invoiceTmp);
            var s3 = this.getCredentials();
            s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, "invoices/" + invoiceName, invoiceTmp));
            invoiceTmp.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("copyInvoice, IOException exception when copying invoice from Stripe", e);
        }
    }
```

When trying on my side, generated invoice downloaded by this code is always in English, even if the linked Customer in Stripe is set as French, invoice account country is FR ([invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-account_country)) and my default JVM locale is fr_FR.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions and advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to define a language when getting the PDF from the Invoice. The language is determined by the browser locale and cannot be set via the API.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Paul. Maybe something to consider for enhancements to come.